# Access rule to display only subordinates leave odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

How can I create a rule to display only subordinates leave records fo group leave/officer  but not for group leave/manager in odoo

Example, **employee1** is Manager of A,B,C, **employee2** is Manager of X,Y,Z, Employees.

**employee1** and **employee2** are assigned to the `leave/Officer` group, and I have **employee3** with a related user assigned to the `leave/Manager` group.

I want to make, **employee1** to be able to see leaves of A,B,C employees only,
and **employee2** to see only leaves of X,Y,Z, and **employee3** to see all leaves( A,B,C,X,Y,Z)

I'v tried the following Rule (domain):

```
['|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id)]
```

here **employee1** and **employee2** fine can see subordinate leaves but **employee3** can't see leaves at all.

Comment: I have used the following rule: ['|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id)] to only allow employees to view their leave applications and have only managers see the subordinates leave applications. However, while applying this rule to everyone (Globally), I would like to still have HR Managers (those given Manager roles i believe its base.group_hr_manager in the module) to be able to see every ones leave request ?

Answer (score -1):

This three user belong to one group or define in different different groups?
if they are belong to same group then 
Try this

> ['|',('parent_id.user_id', '=', user.id),('user_id', '=', user.id)]
>   I hope it's help you.

And if they are belong to other group then you can define related user id 
like

> [('user_id', '=',A,B,C ]

I hope it's works for you.